# Embed vim settings in file

Tags: vim, modeline

In some files I can see a commented line, usually the last, with vim settings. Does vim read these settings? If it does, are any limitations of what kind of settings man can put there?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

They're called modelines and while I'm not sure the extent you can go with them, here's a link to the vimtips wiki with some examples:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic

```
help modeline
```

from within vim to check out the official docs.

Comment: There are security problems with modelines; that's why they're disabled by default. It would probably be better for you to configure per-project .vimrc files. [For example](http://lwn.net/Articles/20249/) , but there are many more.

Comment: All known security problems with modelines have been fixed for years now. Any "dangerous" options, like `'makeprg'` or `'shell'` cannot be set from a modeline. The help is full of options that say at the end "cannot be set in a modeline, for security reasons."

Answer (score 49):

It's this line of code:

```
[other chars]<spaces>vim:<spaces>settings
```

Put it in the first or last few lines of the file, **note it needs < spaces >**. For example:

```
# vim: tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
```

In short version:

```
# vim: ts=2 sw=2 et
```

Put one of the above line in the file, in top or bottom lines, done. For more information, use *vim* help:

```
:h modeline
```

Comment: Expanding on this helpful summary: These lines need to be 'near' the top or bottom of the file. By default, 'near' means it has to be one of the first or last **5** lines of the file. https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Modeline_magic

Comment: Also note everything after `vim:` has to be valid VIM modeline syntax, e.g. you can't use an end-comment delimiter on the same line as the modeline, e.g. `/* vim: ts=2 sw=2 */` will not work.

Comment: spaces are not required other than before vim  I.E.   <space>vim:sw=4:ts=4:et

Comment: This worked in a JSON document on one line 
1515     " vim set sw=4 ts=4 et:": {"type": "keyword"}
Using the short syntax it worked but generated an error.  With the short syntax nothing can follow on the line.

Answer (score 10):

You can check out in the online manual: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline

And this faq item also refers to it: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimfaq.html#19.5

Comment: sorry Rick was faster with one minute :). For this reason I accepted his answer. +1 for links